# Creating a jQuery object from string deleting an element and returning the same string without the deleted element

Tags: jquery

```
s = '<div class="hero"><div id="myDiv"><span id="hello"></span></div><div id="my"><span id="hello"></span></div></div>';

var htmlObject = jQuery(s).find('#my').remove(); //jquery call
alert(jQuery('<div>').append(jQuery(htmlObject).clone()).html());
```

This gives me:

```
<div id="my"><span id="hello"></span></div>
```

But I am expecting:

```
<div class="hero"><div id="myDiv"><span id="hello"></span></div></div>
```

I am looking for a way that doesn't cause memory leak, and I would preferably not modify the DOM, because that's the whole point of it. Modifying the DOM is a big no for this particular situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `.remove()` gives you the removed element. Save the `$(s)` in a variable first, then call `.remove` in a separate line.

```js
const s = '<div class="hero"><div id="myDiv"><span id="hello"></span></div><div id="my"><span id="hello"></span></div></div>';

const jqCollection = $(s);
jqCollection.find('#my').remove();
console.log(jQuery('<div>').append(jqCollection).html());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

No need for a big library like jQuery for this:

```js
const s = '<div class="hero"><div id="myDiv"><span id="hello"></span></div><div id="my"><span id="hello"></span></div></div>';
const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(s, 'text/html');
doc.querySelector('#my').remove();
console.log(doc.body.innerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```